# Anything wrong with this proof on Rubik's cube group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product, rubiks-cube

I'm writing my thesis on semidirect products. As an example, I am proving that the Rubik's cube group $G$ is the semidirect product of its orientation-preserving moves subgroup $C_P$ and position-preserving moves subgroup $C_O$. (In other words, elements of $C_O$ are moves that may change the orientation of a block, but not its position, and elements of $C_P$ are such that they may change the position of a block, but not its orientation.)

I already proved that they're both subgroups of $G$ and $C_O \lhd G$. My proof that $G = C_O \rtimes C_P$ goes like this:

We already know that $C_O \lhd G$. If $g \in C_O \cap C_P$, then $g$ is a move that preserves both position and orientation; the only such move is the neutral move, or the identical permutation. Therefore, $C_O \cap C_P = \lbrace 1_G \rbrace$. Therefore, all is left to show is that $G = C_OC_P$. Obviously, $C_OC_P \subset G$, so we only need to prove that $G \subset C_OC_P$. If $g \in G$, then there are only four possibilities: $g$ preserves both orientations and positions; $g$ preserves only orientations; $g$ preserves only positions; and finally, $g$ preserves neither. In the first case, $g$ is the identity which obviously belongs to $C_OC_P$. In the second case, $g$ changes the position of some blocks, so $g \in C_P$; since $1_G \in C_O$, we have that $g = 1_Gg \in C_OC_P$. In the third case, $g$ changes the orientation of some blocks, so $g \in C_O$; since $1_G \in C_P$, we have that $g = g1_G \in C_OC_P$. Finally, in the fourth case, since $g$ changes both orientation and position of some blocks, there must be $c \in C_O$ and $p \in C_P$ such that $c \neq 1_G$, $p \neq 1_G$, and $g = cp$, whence $g \in C_OC_P$. This concludes the proof.

Initially, I thought this was too brief to be right, and my supervisor also said I probably need more stuff.  Specifically, I was told that while I'm quite correct that the identity permutation is the only position- and orientation-preserving move, my proof doesn't make clear why it is so. Similarly, the bit when I describe the only four possible cases for $g \in G$ is apparently not enough.

I had a look around in books and on the Internet, but couldn't find much. I did find [this](http://tinyurl.com/jrtvqz5) proof (Theorem 1 c), but it is basically a one-liner which seems to say the same things I say, just with fancier notation and more words. Honestly, after having thought about it time and again, I don't see why my proof wouldn't be sufficient. I'm basing my reasoning on the premise that all you can change in Rubik's cube is the position and orientation of a block, and nothing else. If the premise is correct, we only have four options (neither changes, both change, either one changes), and I think my reasoning should work. Can you guys spot any error, contradiction, omission, exception, etc? Thanks!

Comment: The main problem I have with this is that I don't undersatnd the definition of $C_P$. What does it mean for a move to preserve orientation but not position?

Comment: Imagine you are looking at the front face of the cube. Its centre facet is blue. Then imagine the upper-right facet on the front face is green. Since this last facet is not the same colour as the centre facet, its orientation is incorrect. Had they been the same, the orientation would have been correct. If a move preserves orientation, in this specific case it means that after the move is performed, the upper-right facet will still display green; however, the position of the facet may have changed, for example it may have become an upper-left facet on the front face.

Comment: That does not seem like a complete definition. The three facets of the upper right cube could all have colours different from blue, and then it would no chance of having the correct orientation. I am very sceptical about this whole approach. although It is true that $G$ is a semidirect product with normal subgroup $C_O$. (That can be checked by a computer calcualtion.)

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself correctly. Correct orientation isn't defined basing on the colour blue; that was just an example. Of course a block could have all facets different from blue. That would just mean it is on the wrong face of the cube. I think the definition is that a block is correctly oriented when all its facets are of the same colour as the centre facet of the face where they're located.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. This is the definition I'm using:
'A correctly positioned cubie is a corner or edge cubie that is at the right place on the cube relative to its centers regardles how it is twisted in this position. Correctly oriented corner or edge is further twisted so that the sticker of a given color is adjacent to the sticker of the center cubie of the same color.' Source: http://rubikscube.info/concepts.php

Comment: So a correctly oriented cube has to be in the correct position. With that definition your subgroup $C_P$ is trivial, because no cubie can be correctly orineted but in the wrong position.

Comment: No, that's not correct. Check only my comment containing the link. The one immediately before contains a wrong definition from which your deduction would follow. The right definition is that a correctly oriented cube is such that at least one of the facets is adjacent to the centre facet of the same colour.

Comment: Did you take into account that the action on the exterior slices is completely independent from the action on the inner siices. This results in a direct product with a reduced Rubik's cube of 16 cubes with a much simpler group.

Comment: @Nicola: With that definition, the FRU corner cubie _cannot be correctly oriented_ if we move it to BLD position -- and it has _two different correct orientations_ in each of the the BRU, FLU, and FRD positions ...